# booting directly in windows 8.1 after instaling ubuntu 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

i installed ubuntu 12.04 lts over usb drive alongside my windows 8.1 and when installation was finished i pressed restart. And it booted directly in windows without asking me where do i wanted to go windows 8.1 or ubuntu. so how do i go to selection many to chose where i want to boot in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Windows "bcdedit" command http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667(v=ws.10).aspx to re-enable GRUB as your primary boot loader, or install rEFInd http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/ to manage the boot process. More detail on where GRUB2 goes in the process may be had at http://apcmag.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-8-and-linux.htm

Comment: is there any other options this are complicated to mr and i cant wisit last link its unavable

Comment: Fixed the link; sorry for the fat fingers

Comment: thanks man that las link helped me with the boot problem but now i have another problem when i select to boot ubuntu from the grub many ubuntu starts booting for few secs and then the screen goes black, after that in next few secs i hear just like an error sound and that is all it stays black. any idea why that is happening?